# How to return certain keys from an object

Tags: javascript, object, key-value

this is my object:

```
a={"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3","d":"4","e":"5","f":"6"}
```

This returns all the keys:

```
Object.keys(a)
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

This returns all the keys except 'a':

```
Object.keys(a).filter(function(k) {return k !== 'a'})
["b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

how can I return all keys except 1 or more keys for example `a` or `b` or `c`?

I have tried a few permutations but can't seem to get it, 1 below, or maybe it's not possible this way?

```
Object.keys(a).filter(function(k) {return k !== ('a','b')})
["a", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

Comment: `k !== 'a' && k !== 'b'`?

Comment: @Bergi tks think yours is the simplist answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
Object.keys(a).filter(function(k) {
  return ["a", "b"].indexOf(k) === -1;
});
```

Just add the keys you want in the matched Array (*one used with indexOf*)

If you want something more portable:

```
function excludeKeys(obj, keys) {
   return Object.keys(obj).filter(function(k) {
      return keys.indexOf(k) === -1;
    });
}
```

This way you can add any amount of excluded keys.

Comment: "*…all keys **except** 1 or more keys…*"

Answer (score 2):

ES6 (ECMAScript 2015) you can use arrow functions:

```
Object.keys(a).filter(k => !~['a', 'b', 'c'].indexOf(k));
```

ES6 is not supported by all environments, so you can use ES5 alternative:

```
Object.keys(a).filter(function(k) {
    return !~['a', 'b', 'c'].indexOf(k);
});
```

Comment: ES6 doesn't contain `Array.prototype.includes()`, it's ES7

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: In ES6, you'd prefer `new Set("abc").has(k)` :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

var b = a.filter(function(k) {return ['a','b'].indexOf(k) < 0})

// b => [ 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' ]
```